# django poll tutorial admin not showing model edit

Tags: django, admin

I am following the Django Poll tutorial, I just changed the models a little: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/

I am wondering why my alarm does not show in the admin interface when I add/edit/change a pill. The admin only shows to edit the name, not the related alarm object.
It should display inline, according to the tutorial.

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pills.models import Alarm,Pill

class AlarmInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Alarm
    extra = 3

class PillAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Drug information',               {'fields': ['name']}),
    ]
inlines = [AlarmInline]
list_display = ('name')


admin.site.register(Pill, PillAdmin)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Pill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Alarm(models.Model):
    pill = models.ForeignKey(Pill)
    time = models.DateTimeField('Alarm time')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.time.strftime('%c')
```

All my models validate. I tried rebuilding the database etc...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've correctly reproduced your code above, the problem is your indentation.

It should be:

```
class PillAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Drug information',               {'fields': ['name']}),
    ]
    inlines = [AlarmInline]
    list_display = ('name')
```

`inlines` is an attribute of the admin class - it and `list_display` need to be part of the class definition, not statements at the module level.

Comment: Thanks, I copied your indentation structure and it worked. Could you explain where the indentation error was explicitly and why? I didnt understand.

Comment: Your `inlines` and `list_display` declarations were outdented too far.  Indentation controls the class structure - they were declared at the same level as the admin class itself rather than part of the class.